# Sample code to perform validation in Nativescript angular2

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am new to Nativescript coding. I have not found any step by step explanations for doing validation or getting a value of the child view(textfield,button etc) in the module.I know 'ngModel'. But not sure how to access or get the value from the same. I have tried the one which is defined in their groceries app. But still no luck yet. Is there any good sites/blogs available.

Comment: you can see the following thread https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/455#issuecomment-247567932

Comment: another applicable solution i spprovided by RadDataForm http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/DataForm/dataform-validation

Comment: i tried following the github link...but when i tried to access this.user.email or this.user.password, i am getting undefined as value. i want to access these values in my login.ts file so that i can check whether values are empty and take necessary action.

Comment: ,use [(ngModel)]="textVal" in text field ,so you will easily get textfield value by doing this.textVal in typescript class...is this correct?

Comment: using [(ngModel)] provides you with two-way data binding - so Yes, this will allow you to get and validate the value of textVal in your code behind file

Comment: @NickIliev have a html page..lets say login.html
in login.html, in that I have <TextField [(ngModel)]="username"></TextField>
and in login.ts file, I am tryig to alert this value on click of a button

so ,
submit(){  alert("hi > "+this.username);} 
but when i try to access this variable, i am getting undefined error for username
could you please help me
i know in angular 1, this was the procedure
i am not getting enough documents or websites also to get help

Comment: is there any solution for this..the tutorial is so confusing..no simple implemenatitions defined...i also tried the tutorial way of binding, that is using some class object ... [(ngModel)]="record.name"..but when i tried to access it on a button click, its giving undefined...is there any proper way to get the text value...why there is not much of samples or simple implementations....struggling for days...